# Convergence in distribution of logarithm of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Assume  $X_n$ is a series of random variables converging in distribution to a random variable $X$ on some measure space.

I wonder whether the random variable defined by $\log(1+X_n^2)$ also converges in distribution to $\log(1+X^2)$? And also whether the series $\mathbb{E}[\log(1+X_n^2)]$ converges to $\mathbb{E}[\log(1+X^2)]$?

I tried using Levy's theorem by showing the characteristic function $\varphi_{X_n}=\mathbb{E}[e^{it\log(1+X_n^2)}]$ converges pointwise to $\varphi_{X}$, but haven't achieved much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part: yes, by (say) the [portmanteau theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures).  You know that for all continuous bounded $f$ the following holds: $Ef(X_n)\to Ef(X)$, and you want to show that for all continuous bounded $g$ the following holds: $Eg(\log(1+X_n^2))\to Eg(\log(1+X^2)) $.  But if $g(x)$ is continuous and bounded, so is $f(x)=g(\log(1+x^2))$, so you are done before you began.

As for the second part: you need some uniform integrability condition for this to hold.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example for a random variable which isn't uniform integrable?

Comment: The sequence has to be uniformly integrable in the sense explained in   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability. Let $X_n=X$ with probability $1-1/n$ and something horribly huge (such as $\exp(n!)$ with probability $1/n$.  In the special case where the $X_n\to X$ with probability $1$, you can hope to find a bounding random variable to use with the dominated convergence theorem.